# SQL Server Results all possible ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-order-by

I am new to this forum and seeking help on following issue.
I am looking to get all possible ordering from a result set.
e.g

```
Column1
-------
val1
val2
val3
```

Expected Result

```
RowNumCoumn   Column1
-----------   -------
1              Val1         
2              Val2
3              Val3
4              Val1
5              Val3
6              Val2
7              Val2
8              Val1
9              Val3
10             Val2
11             Val3
12             Val1
13             Val3
14             Val1
15             Val2
16             Val3
17             Val2
18             Val1
```

Comment: Paste the expected result properly please.

Comment: Define "all possible ordering"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really hard problem, in my opinion.  My solution uses two recursive CTES:

```
with t as (select * from (values ('a'), ('b'), ('c')) v(col)),
     tn as (
      select row_number() over (order by col) as n, col
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select ',' + cast(n as varchar(max)) + ',' as ordering,
             cast(col as varchar(max)) + ',' as columns,
             1 as lev
      from tn
      union all
      select cte.ordering+ cast(tn.n as varchar(max)) + ',' ,
             cast(cte.columns + tn.col as varchar(max)) + ',',
             lev + 1
      from cte join
           tn
           on cte.ordering not like '%,' + cast(tn.n as varchar(max)) + ',%'
     ),
     orderings as (
      select top (1) with ties cte.*
      from cte
      order by lev desc
     ),
     splits as (
      select ordering, columns,
             left(columns, charindex(',', columns) - 1) as val,
             stuff(columns, 1, charindex(',', columns) , '')  as rest,
             1 as lev
      from orderings
      union all
      select ordering, columns,
             left(rest, charindex(',', rest) - 1) as val,
             stuff(rest, 1, charindex(',', rest), '') as rest,
             lev + 1
      from splits
      where rest like '%,%'
     )
select * 
from splits;
order by ordering, lev;
```

(Of course, the comma is an arbitrary delimiter for the values.  You could change this to anything you want, if the values could already have commas).

The first recursive cte (`cte`) calculates all the possible orderings -- but a single row for each one.  It goes through the data, constructing all possible combinations, one elements at a time.  The cte `orderings` is actually the cte that has the full combinations (of length 3 in this case).  You may find that `orderings` has the information you are looking for.

The second recursive cte (`splits`) then expands the splits to get the results back in rows.

This is an interesting exercise, but I wouldn't run such code on a table with more than a handful of rows.  The number of output rows is n * n! (n factorial).  This grows quite fast quite rapidly.

I should also note that this type of logic is probably more appropriately implemented at the application level, rather than in SQL.  But it is an interesting SQL problem.  After all, there are not many problems where the solution is n * n! rows from the original table.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However the given solution only works if I have 3 rows. 3 Rows given in the example was just for demonstration purpose. It could be any number of rows. I will try other solutions given. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Harry . . . Actually not.  I tested the code with 4 and 5 rows as well.  I wouldn't recommend more than 10 rows.  10 rows is already a result set with 36+ million rows.

Comment: Yes you are right. It works for any number of rows.  Thank you very much for your help. I am marking this as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an odd challenge, given the expected results.

But you can do this via self-joins.
Which can be used to find all the combinations of 3 values.

Then unpivot that result to get the expected result.

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Table table (Column1 varchar(30));

insert into @Table (Column1) values
('val1'),
('val2'),
('val3');

select 
row_number() over (order by rn, Col) as RowNumColumn,
Val as Column1
from
(
    select 
    t1.Column1 as Col1, 
    t2.Column1 as Col2, 
    t3.Column1 as Col3,
    row_number() over (order by t1.Column1, t2.Column1, t3.Column1) as rn
    from @Table as t1
    left join @Table as t2 on t2.Column1 != t1.Column1
    left join @Table as t3 on t3.Column1 not in (t1.Column1, t2.Column1)
) src
UNPIVOT (
    Val 
    FOR Col IN ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3])
) as unpvt
order by RowNumColumn;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried and it worked great for 3 values and did not work for anything more than 3. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Harry True, this method will find every combination of 3 different values.  You can have more than 3 values in the table, but the number of self-joins determines it's calculated per set of 3.  Oh well, guess I understood the requirement differently.